# What is wrong with this ajax.js code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-2

This function is intended to check whether or not a user login exists or might be available, but even with an empty user database table the form always displays that it is a duplicate and thus the submit button goes away. What is wrong with the script?

```js
function cre_username() { /// function
    var cre_username = $('#cre_username').val();

    if (cre_username.length > 0) {
      $.post(base_url() + 'ajax/ch_username/' + cre_username, function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          $('#ch_user').css('color', 'red');
          $('#ch_user').html(' Already Exists ..!');
          $('#cre_username').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 5px 1px red');
          $('#cre_pass').slideUp(500);
          $('#cre_cpass').slideUp(500);
          $('#cre_passl').slideUp(500);
          $('#cre_cpassl').slideUp(500);
          $('#cre_user_submit').attr('type', '').slideUp(100);
        } else {
          $('#ch_user').css('color', 'green');
          $('#ch_user').html(' Available');
          $('#cre_username').css('box-shadow', 'none');
          $('#cre_pass').slideDown(500);
          $('#cre_cpass').slideDown(500);
          $('#cre_passl').slideDown(500);
          $('#cre_cpassl').slideDown(500);
          $('#cre_user_submit').attr('type', 'submit').slideDown(500);

        }
      });
```

Comment: Moved code into a snippet and tried to clarify the language of the question.

Comment: You need to let us know what the server replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, `data == 1` is only checking if there is any sort of data response. It's roughly the same as saying `if (data)`. Chances are, even on failed check, that there is some sort of response.

Try `console.log()`ing your `data` and seeing what the response actually is for a username that you know doesn't exist. Use this response to reform your conditional. Unfortunately, without knowing how exactly your `URL/ajax/ch_username` route is responding, I can't provide code to demonstrate this.

Comment: getting these replies  Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5375:0
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')' ajax.js:75:41
Error: Container is not defined format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:140:451
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5375:0
ReferenceError: base_url is not defined script.js:18:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')' ajax.js:75:41
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Those errors should give you plenty of direction. There are some syntax errors there and an error from the `base_url` function you call in your ajax above. Try sorting those out and see if that doesn't resolve your issues first.